# Jquery hide everything not equal to variable

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I have a table, and when I click on the row name of the table, the row shows.

```
$("#tablerow" + var).show();
```

The variable var represents the number of the current table row.
What I want, every time a new table row shows, I want to hide the row that was selected previously. I want to hide every tablerow with a var not equal to the current var.
I want something like this, but this doensn't work.

```
$("#tablerow" + !var).hide();
```

Hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `:not()` for this:

```
$('table tr:not(#tablerow' + var + ')').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an [attribute *starts-with* selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in combination with
[`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$("tr[id^='tablerow']").each((_, el) => {
  $(el).toggle(el.id === `tablerow${someVar}`)
})
```

---

FYI, `var` is not a valid JS variable name